# FullScreenCover not dismissing - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a .fullScreenCover that opens when I reach a certain point in my app. When I want to dismiss it and reset the app I dismiss the view and set the ContentView ID to a new UUID(). Here is my main App Code:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppState()

    @Published var gameID = UUID()
}

@main
struct RugbyAppApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var appState = AppState.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().id(appState.gameID)
        }
    }
}
```

This should generate a new ID every time I open the ContentView. When I change the gameID using another UUID() in the button to restart, the `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` stops working meaning I can no longer get back to that view.

```
Button("New Game"){
    AppState.shared.gameID = UUID() //Line x
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

Following Cod3rMax's comment, this is how I call the fullScreenCover:

```
Button(action: {endGameAlert.toggle()}) {
    TopPanelButton(buttonText: "End Game", buttonColour: Color.red, buttonWidth: geometry.size.width/10, buttonHeight: geometry.size.width/30)
}
.alert(isPresented: $endGameAlert){
    Alert(title: Text("Are You Sure?"), message: Text("Do you want to end the game?"),
        primaryButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("End Game"), action: {
            stopWatchManager.endGame()                               
            processor.textReport(homeTeam: homeTeam, awayTeam: awayTeam)                                 
            exportToPDF(homeTeam: homeTeam, awayTeam: awayTeam, events: processor.matchEvents)
            showEnd.toggle()
                                                    
        }),
        secondaryButton: Alert.Button.cancel(Text("Cancel"), action: {})
    )
}
}
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showEnd){
    EndGameScreen(homeTeam: homeTeam, awayTeam: awayTeam)
}
```

Comment: can you post the full code

Comment: I have added more code now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are changing the state before the dismissal of the cover sheet. This means that swiftui will reconstruct the view hierarchy and essentially invalidate your presentation mode. Reversing the order of your operations should fix your problem.

Comment: Once I put a few print statements in between it worked! Just allows the view to dismiss before it changes its ID!